# Julia: Console Input Validation

Tags: console, julia

How do you guys handle console input validation? In C++, case/switch is my goto...

I was trying a recursive function but was getting locked in lower levels. Plus that might be overdoing it. I did manage a while loop with an "exclusive or" but, that is not really scalable.

```
function prob6()
  println("Pick a number; any number:")
  x = readline(stdin)
  y = parse(Int64, x)
  z = 0

  println("Select 1 or 2")
  p1 = readline(stdin)
  p2 = parse(Int64, p1)
  select = p2

  while xor((p2 == 1), (p2 == 2)) == false
    println("Select 1 or 2")
    p1 = readline(stdin)
    p2 = parse(Int64, p1)
    select = p2
  end

  if select == 1
    for i in 1:y
      print("$i ")
      z = z + i
    end
  else
    z = 1
    for i in 1:y
        print("$i ")
        z = z * i
      end
    end
  println(z)
end
```

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. I usually create a validation loop to check the type of the input item, and will use tryparse instead of parse, since it will not throw an error if input is malformed:

```
function queryprompt(query, typ)
    while true
        print(query, ": ")
        choice = uppercase(strip(readline(stdin)))
        if (ret = tryparse(typ, choice)) != nothing
            return ret
        end
        println()
    end
end

n = queryprompt("Integer please", Int64)
println(n)
x = queryprompt("Float please", Float64)
println(x)
```

Comment: Far more elegant than mine!